# Reading Rendered data from a website

Tags: java, url, data-extraction

I am trying to extract data from a couple of websites using JAVA. 
I am connecting to a website that has a table.
I need to extract the value from td elements.

The thing is that:
- when I inspect the element in the browser I can see the element and its value in the source.
- When I view the source code in the browser I get the JS.

I am using URL from JAVA jdk 1.8 and when the code below runs I get the unrendered JS instead of the elements the site shows when you visit it.

```
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLConnection;

     URL url = new URL("https://www.example.com");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB;     rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
      while ((f = in.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(f);
        }
        alltext = builder.toString();
        if  (alltext.contains("<td colspan="1">Something</td>")) {
        ...Do something
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the element your saw were created by `javascript` and you can not get these element directly.

In order to get the element data,you need to parse it only after the javascript finished creating elements.

Two solutions for you:

1. **[phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/)**
2. **[selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org)**

Note: it will need you to write more code and cost more time to do it,there is not easy choice in this case